# Efficient way to read and write a Networkx Graph

Tags: python, graph, networkx, large-data

For an open-source project, I am trying to use NetworkX in order to find attractors of Graph (called State Transition Graph). The thing is for nearly 2**33 loops, a function with a variety of inputs returns a list of tuples(nearly 5000 tuples) in which each tuple contains the edges which need to be fed to a networkx graph. It is as follows:

```
def BigGraph:
    #Do some computations
    G = nx.DiGraph()
    for i in range(2**33):
        #Do some computations
        edges = func(different initial conditions)
        G.add_edges_from(edges)
```

As mentioned earlier as the number of edges grow faster and also the fact that NetworkX graph takes up a lot of memory on RAM, I have tried to read and write continuously to a pickle file as follows:

```
def BigGraph:
    #Do some computations
    G = nx.DiGraph()
    nx.write_gpickle(G, 'graph.gpickle')
    for i in range(2**33):
        #Do some computations
        edges = func(different initial conditions)
        G = nx.read_gpickle('graph.gpickle')
        G.add_edges_from(edges)
        nx.write_gpickle(G, 'graph.gpickle')
```

After this, I have realized that as edges go on exponentially, reading and writing to a pickle is gonna effect me a lot of time and memory. I have tried what was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025126/read-write-networkx-graph-object) but as mentioned in that question I don't need to frequently work with Graph. Ultimately, all I need to do is add LOTS of edges to networkx graph with O(1) complexity,if possible.

Is there anyway in which I can do this so that a lot of time can be saved and also won't be a problem to my memory (I have 8 GB of RAM). I am open for using any external libraries as long as they are free and can do what I intended to do in an efficient way.

**EDIT**: I wanted to know if there is a way in which we can use memmap kinda thing to store my graph on my hard disk and find the attracting components of the graph. Using NetworkX is a must for me.

Comment: I don't see why the pickling would avoid the memory problem if you keep reading it in anyways.

Comment: What data type are the nodes?  Integers?  If strings, then there's an immediate memory saving from going to integers.

Comment: @Joel Yeah I have understood why pickling doesn't help me. And also data types of the nodes are integers

Answer (score 1):

You have smaller RAM than you need for this problem.  2**33*5000*2 = 85,899,345,920,000  and depending on how many nodes/edges there are I'm not sure this will work for you.  But there is hope.  This is dependent on the repeated elements if there are a lot then... great.  If not this may not be possible on your machine alone (start thinking of AWS as a platform to run this problem on).

When you are dealing with large datasets you are going to talk about creating generators rather than functions.  (start using that yield keyword).  This filtering process should come first before loading all the data.  Since you are limited in memory for your problem you are going to be writing files.

On the first pass,  I would yield tuple pairs with a generator that keeps track of which ones it has sent (example below).  Since you are using a digraph instead of a multi-digraph then you can take all the edges as tuples and add them to a set() in the generator. This will yield only the unique edges.  If there is a way to loop over the nodes starting with all the edges that start with Node1 then you can subdivide the problem even further putting all the nodes in a for loop and erasing the set() at each new node.  (I don't know what that func(different initial conditions) is capable of)

```
from pathlib import Path
def filter_edges():
    unique_edges = set()
    #Do some computations
    for i in range(2**33):
        #Do some computations
        edges = func(different initial conditions)
        for edge in edges:
            if edge not in unique_edges:
                 yield edge
                 unique_edges.add(edge)

def write_unique_values():
    for edge in filter_edges(): # it's easier on the machine to batch 10,000 or so rather than every line
        Path('edgelist.txt').write_text(edge)

def load_edgelist_to_graph():
    edges = Path('edgelist.txt').read_text().split('\n')
    G = nx.DiGraph()
    G.parse_edges(edges, ...)
    return G

write_unique_values()
G = load_edgelist_to_graph()
```

Save that yielded edge from the generator to a file.  Or even better yet do that in batches of 10000 or so (I'll leave that to homework).

Then you will have a file with unique edges you can load into your graph.

You can parse the edges using [parse_edges](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.edgelist.parse_edgelist.html#parse-edgelist)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this does not quite answer my question. The reason is that 'func' gives very random edges list each time it is ran. And also as I need to find the attracting components of the graph, I need to get all the edges loaded onto my memory into the graph and then calculate the attracting ccomponents. So my question is how to save graph on my disk rather than memory and then compute attracting components.

Comment: Then it sound like you are trying to make an erdos-renyi graph https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.generators.random_graphs.erdos_renyi_graph.html?highlight=erd#networkx.generators.random_graphs.erdos_renyi_graph and find something like centrality and there isn't a terminology called "attracting components" but there is centrality scores.